# Bootstrap buttons to show active state is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a demosite that I'm working on:
http://tanzendesign.com/brightnews

I'm trying to use bootstrap active state button on top fixed menu, but when I click nav button, other button becomes active...

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this navigation being generated dynamically with PHP for example?  Or is it just a static code per page.  If you can change the HTML per-page, then just add the class "active" to the link in the navigation that cooresponds to the page you are editing.

Comment: You should show us code of that area where it's not working and paste the code in your question. Someone may have same problem as you and answer to this question would help him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap's scrollspy to control that highlighting. Make sure scrollspy is being refreshed after all the content has been loaded, and when the browser is resized, so the content area positions can be properly calculated.

```
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
  var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
});
```